# Como generar un archivo builder.xml si no lo tienes por defecto

Tags: java, eclipse

Según tengo entendido, al instalar eclipse-java, tienes instalado por defecto en cada proyecto dentro del paquete builder un archivo xml, pero por alguna razón en todos mis proyectos no tengo ningún archivo xml.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme con este problema?

Answer (score 0):

click en `File -> Export -> General -> Ant Buildfiles` Y especifica el nombre del archivo , proyecto, etc.

Comment: muchas gracias, pero esto funciona para todos los siguientes proyectos o tengo que volver a repetir el mismo proceso cada vez que realice un proyecto nuevo?